# iMessages on Mac consistently disappearing

Tags: iphone, macos, mac, messages

I use iMessages on both my iPhone (6.1.2) and my Retina Macbook (10.8.3). Generally, it works pretty well, but on a somewhat consistent basis messages that I've sent from the Mac will disappear, but only disappear on the Mac. They stay on my phone. It's not a huge deal, but I sometimes like to go review messages via my Mac. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the messages prefs, under the messages tab do you have the "save history when conversations are closed" checked or not?

I generally don't close my conversations so I haven't lost any of my messages but if you regularly close them then this might be the option to check, if you haven't already done so.

Also if you have your main (Apple ID) account listed at the top of all your accounts, and make sure that you have your mobile number listed as the "start new conversations from:" section this, hopefully should solve your problems.

I use messages for iMessage and for Facebook chat but it is also set up for gmail...

Hope that helps

Comment: I did not have "Savehistory when conversatsions are closed" checked, but I have not been closing any conversations...however, it's checked now so hopefully it helps!
And I already had my mobile number listed as "start new conversations from", with my Apple ID listed at the top of all of my accounts (it's also the only account I use in Messages anyways!)

Comment: i am having the same problem and this did not work